# A problem with Cases and Pattern recognition: unexpected behavior

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

I need the following command (to isolate exponents and variables):

```
F[X_] := Cases[ X , G[x_]^m0_. -> {x, m0}]
```

This example gives the correct answer:

```
In:= F[G[a]^4 G[b]^3] 

Out:= {{a, 4}, {b, 3}}
```

Good. But this second example

```
In:= F[G[a]^3] 

Out:= {{a, 1}}
```

is incorrect!  Curiously

```
In:= F[2 G[a]^3]

Out:= {{a, 3}}
```

is correct! What is going on?  I can see that the Heads of the first and third cases are the same (Times) while the second is different (Power). But, how can I get Mathematica to deliver the right output in the second case?

Comment: Your first and third cases work only because the expressions inside `F[]` have head `Times[]`. For the second, you need something like `Cases[G[a]^3, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}, {0}]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiosyncrasy of Cases I always found annoying. You could, until a better solution comes along, do this

```
Clear["Global`*"];
F[X_] := If[Head@X === Times || Head@X === Plus, 
             Cases[X, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}], 
             Cases[{X}, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}]
          ]
```

Alternative way to do the above is as suggested by JM in the comment below, is to change the level spec, either {0} or {1}, based on the head

```
F[X_] := Cases[X, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}, 
             If[MatchQ[Head[X], Plus | Times], {1}, {0}]]
```

Both these definitions achieve the same thing:

And now

```
 F[G[a]^4*G[b]^3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 F[G[a]^3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 F[2 G[a]^3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
   F[G[a]^4 + G[b]^3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to keep your original function instead, then you'd have to change `F[G[a]^3]` to `F[{G[a]^3}]` and then it will work. But the above definition does it automatically inside.

Comment: An equivalent formulation: `Cases[X, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}, If[MatchQ[Head[X], Plus | Times], {1}, {0}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. thanks. This is good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you !  Very useful comments (and I am glad my question made  sense)

Comment: Slightly shorter even: You can use `{Boole[MatchQ[Head[x], Plus|Times]]}` for the level specification

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
F[X_] := (Cases[{X /. G[a_] :> G[a]^p}, G[x_]^m0_. -> {x, m0}, 
     Infinity] /. p :> 1 )[[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

Then

```
F[G[a]^3]
F[G[a]^4 + G[b]^3]
F[G[a]^4 G[b]^3 + G[c]^7]
F[G[a] G[b]^3 + G[c]^7]
```

give

```
{{a, 3}}
{{a, 4}, {b, 3}}
{{a, 4}, {b, 3}, {c, 7}}
{{a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, 7}}
```

I think the problem is caused by the Head of X when there is only one element.

**Updated**

Now the function is

```
F[X_] := ({{something}, {something2}}~Join~
      Cases[{X /. {G[a_] :> G[a]^tempVar, 
          G[b_]^b_ :> G[b]^tempVar2[b]}}, G[x_]^m0_. :> {x, m0}, 
       Infinity] /. {tempVar :>  1, tempVar2[c_] :> c})[[2 ;; ;; 
     2]] /. {{something} :> Nothing, {something2} :> Nothing}
```

(*For test `F[G[a] G[b]^3 G[c]^c + Log[G[g]] + G[c]^7 - G[ap]^p]` gives `{{ap, 1}, {c, 7}, {a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, c}, {g, 1}}`*)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140089/discussion-on-answer-by-curious-cat-a-problem-with-cases-and-pattern-recognition).